# Specific JOIN with 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have 2 tables, `hr_employees` and `hr_positions`.  `hr_positions` contains a field, `designation` that I need to test and see if it matches a query.  Here is my situation:

I need to a count of all employees of a specific shift (`hr_employees.shift`), that are a certain status (`hr_employees.status`), that match a specific designation (`hr_positions.designation`).

Currently I am using the following SQL, but it is throwing the error.  I'm not certain how to JOIN tables 100%, so a little explanation of WHY we did what we did will help me understand this.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM hr_employees he
JOIN hr_positions hp ON he.position = hr_positions.id
WHERE he.id != 0 AND
he.shift = 1 AND
hp.designation != 2
```

Hopefully this is a quick answer.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

Unknown column 'hr_positions.id' in 'on clause' is the error I get.

Comment: What error is it throwing? It would probably also help if you added the table definitions to the question.

Comment: `JOIN hr_positions hp ON he.position = hr_positions.id` use `hp` instead of `hr_positions` since you already named it

Comment: What are your table schemas, it would appear from the error that the `hr_positions` table doesn't have an `id` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM hr_employees he
JOIN hr_positions hp ON he.position = hp.id
WHERE he.id != 0 AND
he.shift = 1 AND
hp.designation != 2
```

You table hr_positions is already named `hp`, use the name in your ON clause

Comment: Thanks everyone.  This is the answer I needed.  Will mark it as answer in a few minutes, when StackOverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

check the following query, you need to specify matching id field

```
SELECT count(*) FROM hr_employees he
JOIN hr_positions hp ON he.id = hp_positions.id
WHERE he.id != 0 AND
he.shift = 1 AND
hp.designation != 2
```